# Facebook Messenger bot url not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, botframework, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have created a test bot using Microsoft bot framework, registered and tested there, all working good.

I have now created a Facebook messenger bot from bot framework UI successfully using this guide(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/bot-framework/channel-connect-facebook)

When ever i go facebook messenger URL provided by Bot Framework (https://www.messenger.com/t/Text-to-Gif-553523584988808), i have been redirected to https://www.messenger.com

Could anyone see this issue before?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you getting the URL (https://www.messenger.com/t/Text-to-Gif-553523584988808)? This URL will only work if you already have a message thread with the given page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the Text-to-Gif- part of the url.

Your url should be: https://www.messenger.com/t/553523584988808. 
I've tested it and that seems to work.